# Swift 2: How to add MapView annotations from a different class and swift file

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TableView with a list of items and a MapView.
I want to touch an item in the TableView and it will be added to the MapView.
Both views are visible at the same time (side by side) so I don't think I can use the MapView's viewDidLoad function. (way too early in the process)
I do understand how to add overlays on the MapView, but not initiated from a different class and swift file.

How do I get access to the map add an overlay on the map from my TableView, since it is in a different class and swift file.

Thanks for any tips and suggestions (and maybe a quick code snip perhaps)
Bryan

Comment: How are you creating the map view? You have to store a reference to it so you can call it later.

Comment: Hi Aaron, the map view was created in the storyboard.  I do have a reference (IBOutlet) to the map view but that reference is in its owning class, not the tableview class.  I think there is something basic/fundamental I am not understanding.  I'm new to ios/swift programming

Comment: you should have a parent view controller that mediates between it's two child view controllers and propagating changes.

Comment: I think I've solved my problem by creating a var myMapView = MapViewController() within my tableview file and then I call the function I want like:  myMapView.thisFunction()

Comment: @Bryan That creates a *new* `MapViewController`. It doesn't reference the one you already have.